# Matlab - Name variable same as File name?

Tags: matlab, file-io

I'm building a facial recognition program and loading a whole bunch of images which will be used for training.

Currently, I'm reading my images in using double loops, iterating through subfolders in a folder.

Is there any way, as it iterates, that the images file name can be used before the image is read and stored?

eg. I have an image `person001.jpg`. How can you retrieve that name (person001) then read the image in like: `person001 = imread('next iteration of loop which happens to be person001');`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can retrieve the contents of a directory using dir(). 
You are essentially looking for dynamic variable name generation, so try genvarname(). It should be pretty straight forward to continue from these two functions.

Comment: Awesome, I'll have to remember that function. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I strongly recommend not to use unstructured variables. First it's very difficult to do operations like "iterate over all images", second you can get strange problems covering a function name with a variable name. Instead i would use a struct with dynamic field names or a map. A solution with a Map propably allows all possible file names.

Dynamic field names:

```
dirlisting=dir('.jpg');
for imageIX=1:numel(dirlisting)
 %cut of extension:
 [~,name,~]=fileparts(dirlisting(imageIX).name);
 allImages.(name)=imread(dirlisting(imageIX).name);
end
```

You can access the images in a struct with `allImages.person001` or `allImages.(x)`

Map:

```
allImages=containers.Map
dirlisting=dir('.jpg');
for imageIX=1:numel(dirlisting)
 %cut of extension:
 [~,name,~]=fileparts(dirlisting(imageIX).name);
 allImages(name)=imread(dirlisting(imageIX).name);
end
```

You can access the images in a Map using `allImages('person001')`. Using a Map there is no need to cut of the file extension.